# How to bind a comma separated string to a Java collection (List) in Spring form?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, csv

I'm stuck in a situation where I've an input element in a JSP where user enters tags. E.g. java, foo, bar, anotherTag..etc

```
<c:url var="saveUrl" value="/create" />
    <form:form modelAttribute="myAttribute" method="POST"
        action="${saveUrl}">

        <form:input path="myTitle" />
        <form:textarea path="myPost" />

        <form:input type="text" id="tagInput"path="???" />

        <input type="submit" value="create" />
</form:form>
```

Now in my domain model corresponding to this input is a

```
private List<Tag> listOfTags
```

How to bind a csv to a List. If I enter listOfTags in the path(which is wrong for obvious reasons), I get incorrect binding exception.
How do I convert(or bind) a csv to a List so that the Spring form is submitted properly and the listOfTags get the tags entered in the JSP.
What is the best way to achieve it?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure but try this. Do a simple html input :

```
<input type="text" id="tagInput" name="myTags" />
```

And then in your controller do something like :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(..., @ModelAttribute("myAttribute") MyClass myAttribute,
                    @RequestParam("myTags") String myTags, ...) {
    ...
    myAttribute.setListOfTags(Arrays.asList(myTags.split(",")));
    ...
}
```

Note : for more generic ways to bind and convert objects, you may want to take a look at [PropertyEditors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439268/how-to-submit-a-form-with-spring-mvc-when-one-of-the-field-is-not-a-string-but-a/12439573#12439573) and [Converters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert).

Comment: I think I'll go with this. Let me try it out. Thanks for the help @Jerome. I shall keep you posted after I try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest try to bind it directly to `listOfTags` property. And to make it work just add contructor with one argument of `String` type (or define static method `valueOf(String)`) to `Tag` class.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you could do something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="10">
    <form:input type="text" path="listOfTags" />
</c:forEach>
```

Where you get the user to enter each tag into a separate text input. This is because Spring will automagically bind multiple inputs with the same form `name` to a List, when it does its binding.

You could use some jQuery sugar to only show one or two and then provide a widget to show more tag inputs. Or even write some cool JS to populate the inputs from a single text input just like StackOverflow does when you add tags.

Comment: Do you think this idea is feasible or is a good solution to my problem? Moreover, how would I know beforehand how many tags the user is going to enter(unless, I make it fixed..like max 5 just like SO).
I think I'll try out the alternative suggested by @Jerome. What is your take on that?

Comment: Yes @Jerome's solution should work fine but has the potential issue of relying on the user to use commas. E.g. It will break if they use spaces or semicolons, etc.

Comment: You're correct & thanks for making me re-think. Now I'll go with JSON as the input. So that even if user enters comma or not, I'll convert it to JSON format & then pass it on to my controller. What say?